# How can I make image-card shrink based on available height, always be max-width/height and have border radius?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have very specific requirements for something with CSS. I have tried many different solutions on stackoverflow but they ended up not working, due to some of the requirements here not being compatible with each other. Even if this might seem like a lot of requirements at first I think they are pretty standard and I tried to be as specific as possible, to make sure all things that could go wrong are covered.

- I have a card

  - The card has an image on top, a header and some text below it. Just a standard card.
  - The top edge of the card (i.e. the top edge of the image) should have border-radius
  - The bottom edge of the card (i.e. the bottom edge of the text-container) should have border-radius
  - The card should have a background shadow
- The cards text-container should always be the same width as the cards image (of course)
- The card should be fixed positioned, since it overlays another element below it
- The card should be as wide & high as it can be, constrained by max-width & by available y-space
- The card should be vertically aligned to the top of the screen
- The card should be horizontally centered
- The aspect ratio of the image should remain unchanged (`object-fit: contain`)
- When the available vertical space for the card gets too small, then the image should shrink, and the text-container should (of course the same for horizontal space, but this seems to happen automatically always)
- the cards text-container can have dynamic content, i.e. if the header-text is too long then it should wrap, if the description-text is two lines long, then the card should be tall enough. This height cannot be determined statically.

#### This is my card:

[image]

#### This is my card, where when it "overflows" in the y-axis, then it does not shrink but instead the overflow gets hidden. Instead its image should shrink while remaining horizontally centered.

[image]

Here is a little code template to get started:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="background: red; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="card-container" style="position: fixed; top: 0; padding: 20px;">
    <div class="card" style="border-radius: 40px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.9)">
      <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1699534956827-a02df22f4e3a?q=80&w=3540&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
           alt=""
           style="
          max-width: 100%;
          max-height: 100%;
          border-radius: 40px 40px 0 0;
         "
      >
      <div style="border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px; padding: 20px; background: grey">
        <div style="font-size: 20px">
          Header Text
        </div>
        <div>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Ofc if it is possible then I would not like to use any javascript to solve this. But if not avoidable then it's fine. Now after having written all this I start to think maybe this actually needs javascript, since to make this work, one would need to hide the text-container of the card when there is not enough y-space to display both the text and the image (and then make also the image have border-radius on the bottom ofc).

Comment: You've included quite a bit of information here that's not at all relevant. We don't care about border radius or shadow. Please see [ask], then simplify as much as possible so you're not wasting your volunteers' time.

Comment: While posting a [repro] pay extra attention to the word **minimal**

Comment: To approach this, the key is going to be "intrinsic" vs "extrinsic" CSS sizing. I would most likely use flex or grid with a gap. Don't have the time right now, but you should also create a jsbin or just the in-line js/html/css editor